# Why do demon slayers other than Shinobu Kocho not use Wisteria in their swords to inject poison in the demons to weaken them?

Tags: demon-slayer

I understand that Shinobu Kocho techniques are designed to inject large portions of Wisteria poison in the demons to kill them, so maybe other demon slayers couldn't kill demons this way. Nevertheless, they could use wisteria poison in the swords to at least weaken the demons when they are fighting them, if they can't kill them.

Why do demon slayers other than Shinobu Kocho not use Wisteria in their swords to inject poison in the demons to weaken them?

Comment: I don't think there's been any explanation for it in the manga

Comment: It's probably related to her specialized katana. The simpe fact that she uses it would mean that simply coating a sword with the wisteria either doesn't work (it dries up, constant exposure to air oxidizes it, many other possible reasons) or doesn't deliver enough poison to visibly affect demons, specially Upper Moons (as seen in the fight with Doma). So the other Hashira would need to use a similar sword, and in doing so, gimping them from using their own skills. Let's not forget that Shinobu uses this technique because she lacks the physical strenght to outright decapitate the demons.

Answer (score 4):

The reason Shinobu Kocho uses Wisteria Poison to fight Demons is because she lacks the physical strength required to behead a Demon, even her student Kanao can do it. So the reason no other Demon Slayer uses Wisteria Poison as regularly as she does because they have no need for it since they can behead most common Demons with little effort, it's only the Twelve Kizuki that give them trouble.

Also, it's important to note that while Shinobu is the only Demon Slayer to rely on Wisteria Poison to fight Demons, doesn't mean she's the only one to use it, as Tengen's wives used throwing knives coated with Wisteria Poison in their fight against Gyutaro and Daki.